# How can i submit review for get "public _content" permission for Instagram API?

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

I want to **get permission(From instagram) for access media of other users and store it in device's gallery**.

"**Basic**" permission already **approved**. But they rejected for **public_content**.

Will i need "public_content" permission to access and save public user's media?

Because without that permission app works correctly.

And can i show ad in my app while i create video screencast for submit for review?, Because in video screencast i displayed ads in it.

I got following ***rejection***:

[image]

I repeat, I only **need to access public user's media and user can store that media in his device's gallery**.

And they provide 3 types of use case:

1. to help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps.
2. to help brands and advertisers understand and manage their audience and digital media rights.
3. to help broadcasters and publishers discover content, get digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution.

So, ***which use case i have to choose?***

Comment: did you solve this problem ? I have same problem

Comment: Not, I can't overcome from this.

Comment: same here,  I will beck to you if I get any happy news

Comment: It would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone got the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

public_content scopes are no longer accepted. Instagram deprecated this scope. Now, Insta privacy doesn't let you have access for the feed of your followers. you can only access your medias and their comments from API.